# LINQ Querying Against DataSet

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, traversal

I Want to print out the number of tables in a Typed dataset along with the number of fields associated with each table and the key fields { primary,foreign}. How to get this information using LINQ?

Comment: That's not exactly what linq is for.  Dunno if you can get the schema from a STD (lol), if you can you could use linq to xml.  Otherwise its reflection all the way.

Answer (score 5):

Even with it being a typed dataset you can still use the DataTables property of the DataSet and the DataColumns propety of the DataTable.  However, to use Linq with these you have to call `.OfType<DataTable>()` or `.OfType<DataColumn>()` on the appropriate property to turn it into an IEnumerable<> so that you can run Linq queries against them.  After that you should just have to check the appropriate properties to find out what is a Primary Key or Foreign Key.  I am not sure on the last part if there is a property for these values or if you have to check the Data Relations to determine this.

EDIT:
There is actually a PrimaryKey property on the DataTable that will return an Array of the DataColumns which make up the PrimaryKey.  For the foreign keys though I believe you have to dig into the DataRelations collection to determine what columns are foreign keys.